# invalid comparison between distintc pointer types: 'type*' and 'type&(*)()'

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

I cannot understand why the compiler is complaining about a bad comparison attempt.

The offending comparison is this:

```
method(const APFloat& V) {
...
    if (&V.getSemantics() == &APFloat::IEEEdouble) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

And here are the type declarations of the compared items:

```
const fltSemantics &getSemantics() const;
static const fltSemantics &IEEEdouble();
```

The error indicated by the compiler looks like this:

**comparison between distinct pointer types 'const llvm::fltSemantics*' and 'const llvm::fltSemantics& (*)()' lacks a cast [-fpermissive]**

Can anybody help me understand this? I am a beginner but to me it looks both terms in the comparison are of type *const fltsemantics &&*.

PS: I am compiling with gcc and C++11 compliance.

Comment: You're missing a `()` after `&APFloat::IEEEdouble`, so you're comparing a pointer to a `fltSemantics` to a function pointer

Comment: Also, according to [this](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html#aac03c2635e359347d396ddf4d7963b89) the function returns by value, not reference.

Comment: Thank you two.

I cannot blame the code for my lack of understanding of basic concepts, however this code is not mine. I think it's old LLVM code that was written when the API was pretty different. I am trying now to compile it against one of the latest LLVM versions and there is plenty of such errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to me it looks both terms in the comparison are of type const fltsemantics &&.

There is no such type as `fltsemantics&&`, so neither expression can have such type.

> ```
> V.getSemantics()
> ```

This is a function invocation (a function call). We know that it is an invocation, because of the argument list `()`. The type of the expression is `fltSemantics&` because that is what the function returns.

> ```
> &V.getSemantics()
> ```

When applied to a reference, the addressof operator returns a pointer to the referred object. So, the type of the addressof expression is `fltSemantics*`.

> ```
> APFloat::IEEEdouble
> ```

This is the name of a function. There is no function call, because there is no argument list. The type of the function is `type&()`.

> ```
> &APFloat::IEEEdouble
> ```

When applied to a function name, the addressof operator returns a function pointer. The type of the function pointer is `type&(*)()` in this case.

---

I suspect that you intended to call both of the functions, and compare the return values. To call `APFloat::IEEEdouble`, you need the (empty) argument list:

```
APFloat::IEEEdouble()
```

Comment: Your answer has just made me realize I was having serious misunderstandings of how references and the addressOf operator work. Thanks!

Comment: And of some other things as well :/

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an object pointer to a function pointer, fix:

```
method(const APFloat& V) {
...
    if (&V.getSemantics() == &APFloat::IEEEdouble()) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks I had not understood very well how references work, among other things :)

Answer (score 0):

`&APFloat::IEEEdouble` evaluates to a pointer to a function while `&V.getSemantics()` evaluates to a pointer to a `const llvm::fltSemantics*`. That's why you can't compare them.

You can use:

```
if (&V.getSemantics() == &APFloat::IEEEdouble()) {
```

to get past the compiler. However, that does not seem right. You probably want to compare the values returned by the functions, not the pointers to those values. In that case, you need to use:

```
if (V.getSemantics() == APFloat::IEEEdouble()) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer mades it clear, but I decided to chose another one just because it's more detailed.

Comment: About "not seeming right"... indeed. It's not my code and I am just trying to make it compile in order to start debugging it and grasping how it works.

Comment: @AmazingWouldBeGreatBut, no worries. It's important that you were able to understand the problem and were able to resolve it.